# Comparing Two Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have two NSArrays, what I'm looking to do is to compare two arrays which contain strings, find the similarities and create the first array again but so they have no similarities.

Just for an example something like.

Two Arrays:

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TD1", @"TD2", @"TD3", nil];
NSArray *arrayTwo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blah", @"String", @"TD2", nil];
```

Outcome:

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TD1", @"TD2", @"TD3", nil];

NSArray *arrayOneCopy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TD1", @"TD3", nil];
NSArray *arrayTwo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Blah", @"String", @"TD2", nil];
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOneCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayOne];
[arrayOneCopy removeObjectsInArray:arrayTwo];
```

Answer (score 28):

Use [NSMutableSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/index.html):

```
NSMutableSet *setOne = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: arrayOne];
NSMutableSet *setTwo = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: arrayTwo];

[setOne minusSet: setTwo];

NSArray *arrayOneResult = [setOne allObjects];
```

(strictly speaking, `setTwo` doesn't have to be mutable, can also be an `NSSet` (which performs better))

Or use NSArray as the other person answered -- that works, too.

Which one works depends entirely on your data set size.  For small sets of data, the array solution works fine.  For larger sets, NSSet will be much more efficient in that membership tests are a hash check and not a linear search.

Measure and use the one that works best.

Comment: If the order of the items in the array is important, then I guess one would have to use the other solution with NSArray, right?

Comment: Good answer, but like you said, I am only using small sets of data so I am going to use the other solution. Thanks Anyway!

Comment: Yup-- for small data sets, "newacct"'s answer is the way to go.

Comment: Make sure you use NSMutableSet for setOne to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSInteger)countOfDifferentObjects:(NSArray *)anotherArray {

    NSSet * s = [NSSet setWithArray:self];
    NSMutableSet * s1 = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:s];
    NSSet * s2 = [NSSet setWithArray:anotherArray];

    [s1 unionSet:s2];
    [s1 minusSet:s];
    return [s1 count];
}
```

This returns the number of different objects between two arrays (comparison is with isEqual)

```
array1 = @"A", @"B", @"C"
array2 = @"B", @"D", @"Z"
returns 2 (D and Z are different)
```