# Removing ALAssets in one Array from another

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I have an array containing my camera roll `ALAssets`.  In addition I have custom album containing `ALAssets`.  I would like to remove the custom album assets from the camera roll `ALAssets` array.  Thereby having an array containing the camera roll minus the assets in the custom album.  I'm able to create the arrays containing both the camera roll assets and the custom album assets but I'm unsure how to then remove the unwanted assets.

Comment: Are you trying to delete from the camera roll, or just filter the camera roll?

Comment: Filter it.  At the moment I'm enumerating and comparing in the background.

Comment: There's two solutions in this question that should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649198/objective-c-how-to-compare-arrays-and-extract-the-difference

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I have originally tried this but must have had some other issue elsewhere as it didn't work.  Revisiting this has resolved it.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work.  It doesn't remove the assets.