# Swift - Determine if Array1 contains at least one object from Array2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arraylist

I have 2 Arrays. Say, `array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `array2 = [2,3]`. How could I check in swift if `array1` contains at least one item from `array2`?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array for some ideas what can be done with `Array` and `Set`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can do this by simply passing in your `array2`'s [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FesRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_s9EquatablerS_8containsFWxS0_S1__Sb) function into your `array1`'s [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb) function (or vice versa), as your elements are `Equatable`.

```
let array1 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
let array2 = [20, 15, 2, 7]

// this is just shorthand for array1.contains(where: { array2.contains($0) })
if array1.contains(where: array2.contains) {
    print("Array 1 and array 2 share at least one common element")
} else {
    print("Array 1 doesn't contains any elements from array 2")
}
```

This works by looping through array 1's elements. For each element, it will then loop through array 2 to check if it exists in that array. If it finds that element, it will break and return true – else false.

This works because there are actually two flavours of `contains`. One takes a closure in order to check each element against a custom predicate, and the other just compares an element directly. In this example, `array1` is using the [closure version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb), and `array2` is using the [element version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FesRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_s9EquatablerS_8containsFWxS0_S1__Sb). And that is the reason you can pass a `contains` function into another `contains` function.

---

Although, as [correctly pointed out by @AMomchilov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299385/swift-determine-if-array1-contains-atleast-one-object-from-array2/37299483#comment62127288_37299814), the above algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>). A good set intersection algorithm is O(n), as element lookup is O(1). Therefore if your code is performance critical, you should definitely use sets to do this (if your elements are `Hashable`), [as shown by @simpleBob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299814/2976878).

Although if you want to take advantage of the early exit that `contains` gives you, you'll want to do something like this:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : Hashable {

    func intersects<S : Sequence>(with sequence: S) -> Bool
        where S.Iterator.Element == Iterator.Element
    {
        let sequenceSet = Set(sequence)
        return self.contains(where: sequenceSet.contains)
    }
}
```

```
if array1.intersects(with: array2) {
    print("Array 1 and array 2 share at least one common element")
} else {
    print("Array 1 doesn't contains any elements from array 2")
}
```

This works much the same as the using the array's contains method – with the significant difference of the fact that the `arraySet.contains` method is now O(1). Therefore the entire method will now run at O(n) (where n is the greater length of the two sequences), with the possibility of exiting early.

Comment: Simple and best solution!

Comment: @iOS Happy to help :)

Comment: Could you include a link to some documentation for the contains function? Thanks.

Comment: @Arc676 In my third paragraph I have links to both [the closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb) and [element](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FesRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_s9EquatablerS_8containsFWxS0_S1__Sb) `contains` functions – I will add a link in the first paragraph though :)

Comment: And how about  different of 2 objects list, at least one property contain?. this  answer just the same two object list. I's stucking on this. haha

Comment: @LeangSocheat Not entirely sure what you mean; it would probably be best if you [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) giving a clear example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 18):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the following paths in order to find if two arrays have common elements or not.

---

## #1. Using `Set` `isDisjoint(with:)` method

`Set` has a method called [`isDisjoint(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1781892-isdisjoint). `isDisjoint(with:)` has the following declaration:

```
func isDisjoint(with other: Set<Element>) -> Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the set has no members in common with the given sequence.

In order to test if two arrays have no common elements, you can use the Playground sample code below that implements `isDisjoint(with:)`:

```
let array1 = [1, 3, 6, 18, 24]
let array2 = [50, 100, 200]

let hasNoCommonElement = Set(array1).isDisjoint(with: array2)
print(hasNoCommonElement) // prints: true
```

---

## #2. Using `Set` `intersection(_:)` method

`Set` has a method called [`intersection(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853807-intersection). `intersection(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func intersection<S>(_ other: S) -> Set<Element> where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence
```

> Returns a new set with the elements that are common to both this set and the given sequence.

In order to test if two arrays have no common elements or one or more common elements, you can use the Playground sample code below that implements `intersection(_:)`:

```
let array1 = [1, 3, 6, 18, 24]
let array2 = [2, 3, 18]

let intersection = Set(array1).intersection(array2)
print(intersection) // prints: [18, 3]

let hasCommonElement = !intersection.isEmpty
print(hasCommonElement) // prints: true
```

Comment: I'd be glad to have the confirmation from someone who really knows about this stuff (not me), but I'd imagine that `isDisjoint(with:)` is more performance efficient than doing `!intersection.isEmpty`?

Answer (score 16):

An alternative way would be using [Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID484)s:

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let array2 = [2,3]
let set1 = Set(array1)
let intersect = set1.intersect(array2)

if !intersect.isEmpty {
    // do something with the intersecting elements
}
```

Comment: This would probably be the best way. O(n) vs O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

#### Swift 5

Just make an extension

```
public extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    func contains(anyOf sequence: [Element]) -> Bool {
        return self.filter { sequence.contains($0) }.count > 0
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let someArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
let string = "onE, Cat, dog"

let intersects = string
                   .lowercased()
                   .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                   .components(separatedBy: ",")
                   .contains(anyOf: someArray)
print(intersects) // true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let a1 = [1, 2, 3]
let a2 = [2, 3, 4]
```

### Option 1

```
a2.filter { a1.contains($0) }.count > 1
```

### Option 2

```
a2.reduce(false, combine: { $0 || a1.contains($1) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
//
//  Array+CommonElements.swift
//

import Foundation

public extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    func set() -> Set<Array.Element> {
        return Set(self)
    }

    func isSubset(of array: Array) -> Bool {
        self.set().isSubset(of: array.set())
    }

    func isSuperset(of array: Array) -> Bool {
        self.set().isSuperset(of: array.set())
    }

    func commonElements(between array: Array) -> Array {
        let intersection = self.set().intersection(array.set())
        return intersection.map({ $0 })
    }

    func hasCommonElements(with array: Array) -> Bool {
        return self.commonElements(between: array).count >= 1 ? true : false
    }
}
```