# How to remove one duplicate value in an array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays for which I am comparing [Int]

```
let filter = strongAgainstArray.filter{weakAgainstArray.contains($0)}
```

This returns an array of common values in the 2 arrays.  I then want to go through and remove those values from each array, which I'm doing like so

```
for item in filter {
    for var i = 0; i < strongAgainstArray.count; i += 1 {
        if item == strongAgainstArray[i] {
            strongAgainstArray.removeAtIndex(i)
            print("Removing a Strong against index \(item)")
        }
    }
    for var i = 0; i < weakAgainstArray.count; i += 1 {
        if item == weakAgainstArray[i] {
            weakAgainstArray.removeAtIndex(i)
            print("Removing a Weak against index \(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but let's say one of my arrays contains two entries for `12` as an example.  How do I only remove one of them?  As it stands, all entries of `12` are being removed entirely.

EDIT

I'm now comparing my two arrays using

`let commonValues = Array(Set(strongAgainstArray).intersect(weakAgainstArray))`

and then those `commonValues` from each array with

```
cleanStrongAgainstArray =  Array(Set(strongAgainstArray).subtract(Set(commonValues)).sort())

cleanWeakAgainstArray = Array(Set(weakAgainstArray).subtract(Set(commonValues)).sort())
```

This is a much better overall solution, but I'm still eventually running into the same issue, albeit slightly different than before.

In the playground, for example...

```
let array = [7,7,9]
let test = Array(Set(array))
```

test comes back containing `[7, 9]`, and I need to keep that extra 7.  How do I do that?

Comment: If the values in your arrays are unique within themselves, you should consider using Sets as they have built in methods for these kinds of operations. As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of the array?

Comment: Also one thing to note, structuring your loop like this can cause problems since you are changing the length of the array while looping through it.

Comment: I've switched to using Sets, and no order is not important.  I've greatly simplified the code, but my problem still stands.  Will update original post shortly

Comment: @john_ryan Thanks for pointing that out. You're right.  I've corrected the issue

Answer (score 5):

If the order of the arrays aren't important then you can easily achieve the whole solution using Sets:

```
let dirtyArray = [1,4,6,1,56,4,4,66,23,3,3,12]
let dirtyArray1 = [3,1,6,99,54]

let cleanArray = Array(Set(dirtyArray).union(Set(dirtyArray1)))

print (cleanArray)
```

> [12, 54, 23, 4, 6, 66, 99, 56, 1, 3]

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than what I was using, but I'm still having issues.  It looks like any time I'm converting an `Array` to `Set` It's combining common values.  `[7, 7, 9]`, for example, becomes `[7, 9]` after converting

Answer (score 2):

If order is important, use `NSOrderedSet`:

```
let strongAgainstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let weakAgainstArray = [3, 4, 5, 6]

let result = NSOrderedSet(array: (strongAgainstArray + weakAgainstArray)).array
```