# Swift Array intersection by property

Tags: arrays, swift, set, intersection

I am trying compare two arrays. One array is an array of `Person` objects, each of which has an `email` property that is a `String` email address. The other array is an `EmailAddress` object which has a descriptive word like "work" or "personal" and the actual `String` email address.

Basically both objects have a `String` property for email address. I want to compare these arrays of objects to see if one of the objects from each array has the same email address. Right now I am using nested `for` loops as shown below but that is taking too long.

```
for person in self.allPeople! {
    for e in EmailAddresses! {
        if e.value == person.email {
             return true               
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about using [set intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29852086/3179636) but that looked like it would only work for comparing the same objects and not object's properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `Set` functionality by first creating a set of all the emails. `map` helps turn one collection into another, in this case changing your collection of `allPeople` into a collection of those people's `email`s. This will be faster because now `EmailAddresses` is iterated once, instead of once *per person*.

```
let personEmails = Set(self.allPeople!.map { $0.email })
let matchingEmails = EmailAddresses!.map { $0.value }
return !personEmails.isDisjoint(with: matchingEmails)
```