# Find matching elements in array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have two arrays filled with strings and am hoping to identify the matching strings in both arrays. Eg.

```
var ArrayOne = ["Dog", "Cat", "Chicken"]
var Array Two = ["Dog", "Elephant", "Chicken", "Sheep"]
```

I am wanting the outcome to be

```
["Dog", "Chicken"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array

Comment: `let matching = Set(ArrayOne).intersection(ArrayTwo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ArrayOne = ["Dog", "Cat", "Chicken"]
var ArrayTwo = ["Dog", "Elephant", "Chicken", "Sheep"]

var ArrayThree = [String]()
for animal in ArrayOne {
    if ArrayTwo.contains(animal) {
        ArrayThree.append(animal)
    }
}
```