# Getting Un common element from small array to large and vice - versa

Tags: swift, set

I am using  `subtracting` for getting un-common element which is working fine.

but not working if both array has different number of elements (count)

like

I have array

```
fileprivate var daysSelected:[Schedule.ScheduleDays] = [] {
    didSet {
        if let array =  equipment.schedules?.map({$0.day}), Set(array).subtracting(Set(daysSelected)).count > 0{
            debugPrint("After updated days ",array)
            daySelectionChanged = true
        } else {
            daySelectionChanged = false

        }
        debugPrint("After updated days ",self.daysSelected)

    }
}

enum ScheduleDays: String {
    case everyday
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
    case thursday
    case friday
    case saturday
    case sunday
}
```

If `array` has less element then  `daysSelected` it is returns 0

So Is there any work around that get un - common element from two array which has different count without check such a `array.count  >  daysSelected`

Example 
Suppose `daysSelected` has

```
  - 0 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.tuesday
  - 1 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.thursday
  - 2 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.friday
  - 3 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.saturday
  - 4 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.sunday
  - 5 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.wednesday
  - 6 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.monday
```

and another set has

```
  - 0 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.friday
  - 1 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.saturday
  - 2 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.sunday
  - 3 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.tuesday
  - 4 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.wednesday
```

When I

```
Set(equipment.schedules!.map({$0.day})).subtracting(Set(daysSelected))
0 elements
```

and

```
 po Set(daysSelected).subtracting(Set(equipment.schedules!.map({$0.day})))
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.thursday
  - 1 : App.Schedule.ScheduleDays.monday
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array ? What you want is not `union` nor `intersection` but `symmetricDifference`?

Comment: @Larme What is both array has different count let me update with more context

Comment: @Larme symmetricDifference is what I am looking thanks for quick help :) Please add answer I will accept it

Comment: I flagged the question as duplicate. If you think that yours doesn't provide more help you can delete it. If you think that users might easier find yours instead of the linked one (choice of words to describe your issue, etc.) and then could be redirected, then mark it as duplicate yourself (it's quicker than waiting for other 4 flag/votes)).

Comment: @Larme yes I have marked my answer  as duplicate, But Yes you are right with given link of answer has not provided that enough information or that  not well documented that user can easily catch his required function .However I have explained my problem well enough as per my knowledge (my english skills :D )