# The simplest way to find the differences between two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays

```
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>deviceStartList")
dump(deviceStartList)
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

and

```
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>deviceEndList")
dump(deviceEndList)
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

It product this result:

[image]

I came from a PHP background when I can just call `array_diff()` , done.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array.

Comment: Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question and show example data and your expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to do something like set subtraction, Swift has that. See [Set operations (union, intersection) on Swift array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589181/set-operations-union-intersection-on-swift-array#29852086).

The title of the SO post above doesn't *per se* mention the methods `subtract(_:)` or `subtracting(_:)`, but the content of the accepted answer does cite `subtract(_:)`.

In **Swift 4.1**, You could do something like:

```
var deviceStartList = ["12345", "67890", "55555", "44444"]
var deviceEndList = ["12345", "55555"]

var deviceStartSet = Set<String>(deviceStartList)
var deviceEndSet = Set<String>(deviceEndList)

let devicesDiff = deviceStartSet.subtracting(deviceEndSet)
```

And if you need an array as the final output, you can get that by doing this:

```
var devicesDiffArray = [String](devicesDiff)
```

Here is a screenshot of a Playground with this working:

[image]

Comment: As @Sh_Khan's answer says, using the **Swift Standard Library** `Set` operations (...or `NSSet` from **Foundation** if you wanted) would be better. `Set` and `NSSet` are optimized in terms of time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let result = deviceStartList.filter { deviceEndList.contains($0) == false }
```

Also I strongly recommend the **Set** way as it's internally optimized rather than the usual way

Answer (score 1):

This is Set way. Hope it's working for you.

```
var a=["B8D7","38C9","484B", "F4B7"]
var b=["484B","F4B7"]
Set(a).symmetricDifference(Set(b))
```