# Get an array of deselected indexPaths of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

It's easy to get an array of selected rows of UITableView object by calling

```
[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Is there any way to get an inverted array of **deselected** rows of my tableView?

Comment: define "deselected row", please.

Comment: I mean an array of tableViewCells that have their property "selected" equals NO. And I want to obtain an array of indexPaths of such cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *unselectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

NSInteger sectionCount = self.tableView.numberOfSections;

for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
    NSInteger rowCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];

    for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
        [unselectedIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]];
    }
}

[unselectedIndexPaths removeObjectsInArray:self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

Answer (score 2):

You know the index paths of the selected rows. You also know how many sections your table view has and how many rows per section.

Total rows - selected rows = not selected rows.

Comment: Yes, it will work, I agree. But in this case I have to generate an array of all indexPaths my tableView has. I just would like to avoid this... if it's possible, of course )

Comment: @Miroslav I don't think you can. Check out UITableView class reference from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html Looks like there is not any method that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to you get those `NSIndexPath` objects, because the `UITableView` doesn't create all indexes in same time. For optimization question, the `NSIndexPath` objects will be created "on demand".

But you can extract the selected items from your source array to create a new one with non selected items.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475636/comparing-two-arrays/1475656#1475656) to you get some ideas about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And call the same method

```
[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```